# Convert MBR to GPT - Without any OS

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I just got a new laptop without any OS (it had FreeDOS, but not anymore). When I go to Windows Installer and try to create a new partition from un-allocated space, I don't get any Error message but the installer is unable to create the partition. At the bottom of the installer window, there's a warning which says something like,

> Windows cannot install on MBR *partition. On EFI systems, Windows can only install on GPT *partition

How can I convert MBR to GPT *partition without any OS?

*I am not sure if it was partition or not

Comment: I would find a bootable Linux disk that will allow you to format the hdd as a GPT partition. Here is one such tutoral and tool http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#MBR2GPT and http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/index.html

Comment: You don't need any third-party utilities or LInux boot disks.  You can do this from Windows Setup.  Just follow the instructions in Anonymous hacker's post.

Comment: You can use third-party tool like EaseUS Partition Master which might hep you to convert MBR to GPT https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-mbr-to-gpt-during-windows-installation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a live distro of [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) I believe.

This is a fairly generic tool which allows a number of operations to be performed on drives whilst booted up from a USB stick or CD-ROM

Answer (score 7):

This is easy, when you go through installation guide, you can at any time press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> - the command prompt will show up.

Then write `Diskpart`, then `List Disk`. You see there a list of your disks, then select the one you want to convert.

`Select disk 0` (if you want to install on the first disk, for an example).  Clean it with `Clean`, and convert into GPT `Convert GPT`. Enjoy

Unluckily I wanna MBR and got GPT :/